# uiscrollview strange offset

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, storyboard

I have a issue that my viewDidLayoutSubviews creates a strange offset between my table wiche is right under the view and my view

I for example uncomment this section of my code and scroll in my table this content view diapers as soon as I start to scroll
looks like this:

[Offset between view and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XwcM.png)

I really do not have a clue why this exists. The problem is not regarding the constrains I have tested it with connecting the view with the code and not.

What I do

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.TableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.ContainerView.frame.size.height, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f)];
    [self.TableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];

   float headerImageYOffset = 88 + self.ContainerView.bounds.size.height - self.view.bounds.size.height;
   CGRect headerImageFrame = _ContainerView.frame;
   headerImageFrame.origin.y = headerImageYOffset;
}
```

What I do when I scroll

```
    -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat scrollOffset =-scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat yPos = scrollOffset - _obergurglContainerView.bounds.size.height;
    _obergurglContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, yPos, _obergurglContainerView.frame.size.width, _obergurglContainerView.frame.size.height);
    float Alpha = 1.0-(-yPos/_obergurglContainerView.frame.size.height);
    _obergurglTitleImageView.alpha = Alpha;
    NSLog(@"THE Alpha Value : %f",  Alpha);
    NSLog(@"The off set of the scroll view is %f",scrollOffset);
}
```

Thanks for help and fast answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

So reading again the question I figured out about your problem.
I think you shouldn't use viewDidLayoutSubviews.

viewDidLayoutSubviews is called all the time while you are scrolling, which is modifying the inset in your tableview all the time.

try to place

```
[self.TableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.ContainerView.frame.size.height, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f)];
```

where you create your tableview.

Comment: for example if  I remove the hole method viewDidLayoutSubviews and put this what you posted in view did load nothing changes at all and I posted what I do when I scroll